# How is Comparator<T> a Functional Interface?

Tags: java, oop, functional-interface

According to definition of functional interface - **A functional interface is an interface that contains only one abstract method.**

But `Comparator<T>` has two abstract methods:

```
int compare(T o1, T o2);

boolean equals(Object obj);
```

others are default and static.

JavaDocs mentions it as functional interface. How can it be?

Comment: I actually prefer the answers given here, though, perhaps they should be merged to the dupe?

Answer (score 8):

You're reading the wrong definition, or at least, an (over)simplified one.

The proper definition of a FunctionalInterface is:

> A functional interface is an interface that has just one abstract method (aside from the methods of Object), and thus represents a single function contract. This "single" method may take the form of multiple abstract methods with override-equivalent signatures inherited from superinterfaces; in this case, the inherited methods logically represent a single method.

SOURCE: [Java Language Specification section 9.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the source code of `Comparator<T>` , it is like below:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Comparator<T> {

  // abstract method
  int compare(T o1, T o2);

  // abstract method, overriding public methods of `java.lang.Object`, so it does not count
  boolean equals(Object obj);

}
```

The `equals` is an abstract method overriding one of the public methods of `java.lang.Object`, this doesn’t count as an abstract method.

So In fact The Comparator only has one abstract method i.e `int compare(T o1, T o2)`, and it meet the definition of functional interface.

Answer (score 3):

`equals` is only explicitly included in the `Comparator` interface so that they can add some additional JavaDocs to it, e.g. some comparator-specific requirements:

> this method can return true only if the specified object is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator

Source: [Comparator JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

[The JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1.2) says:

> interfaces do not inherit from Object, but rather implicitly declare
> many of the same methods as Object ([§9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2))

So all the `Comparator` authors have done is declare something explicitly that is normally implicit.

If the methods of `Object` counted as abstract methods for the purposes of defining a functional interface then **no** functional interface would have just a single abstract method. As such, they are not considered:

> A functional interface is an interface that has just one abstract
> method **(aside from the methods of Object)**

[JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8), emphasis mine

Comment: So, is equals an abstract method or just like default method?

Comment: @JasHanChaHal It is an abstract method, just not one that is considered as part of determining functional interface status. Updated my answer

Comment: The declaration on the interface is abstract, it wouldn't make sense to add a default implementation - that would never be used, because the `equals` method in `Object` is not abstract.

Comment: @Hulk Indeed, and it's prohibited: "*It is a compile-time error if a default method is override-equivalent with a non-private method of the class Object, because any class implementing the interface will inherit its own implementation of the method*"